# Options for mapping / mounting remote FS on Mac hosting linux in a VM

Tags: ubuntu, mac, nfs

Just got a new mackbook and willing to keep working on my linux box as I used to.
My idea is to have the linux box running virtually on the mac, and while I am editing code in the mac environment, I am running all things on the ubuntu using SSH.

I wonder what are is the what is best option to have a remote fs mounted locally, best == performance+stability, considering security is not an issue (it is all done inside the box).

Comment: Samba or Virtualization software's file sharing tools.

Comment: @kobaltz used the built-in "folder-share" option. thanks.